# PhoneGap: how to include a picture in an alert

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In a PhoneGap application,
using the: navigator.notification.alert("message");
How would you display an image and how would you style text?
Could you do html code inside there, in order to format text?

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function click() {
        navigator.notification.alert("hello world");

   }
</script>
<p><input id="Button1" type="button" value="Test alert" onclick="return click()" /></p>
```

Where it says "hello world", could that be a picture? and how would I make that text red or blue or even some hex-code color?

Comment: navigator.notification.alert doesn't support pictures, but I think it's possible to add a picture to an AlertDialog, so you can create your own plugin based on notification plugin with picture support

Comment: Just override the current AlertDialog plugin..or create your new one